# re-enable intel on-board vga without display

Tags: bios, reset

I have a DB85FL desktop board which appears to be faulty and i managed to lock myself out of it. I was trying out a new PCIe VGA but it would not show under windows or even in bios setup under pci devices (shows as unpopulated). As a last resort I disabled primary on-board display and now i cant get back in. the system beeps 2 long beeps then pauses a bit and repeats (so 4 beeps in total which is code for video error as the manual says).
I have tried every tutorial out there on resetting the CMOS. removed the jumper completely like described in the manual for resetting, switched to position 2-3 instead of 1-2, removed battery for several hours with psu both connected and disconnected, left it for several hours, shorted the + and - battery contacts while residual power was still present (led was on), you name it! nothing is resetting the bios to default back to the on-board vga. what's interesting is im sure it's booting into windows, im checking on my dhcp clients and verify that indeed its acquiring an IP address. I cant remote desktop since it appears to be disabled.

when i remove the jumper and turn on the computer, the beeping is gone. ive tried to guess restoring default values in bios while working "BLIND", as in pressing F9 --> Y --> enter --> F10 ... and so on (its intel visual bios). also tried blindly using the power button menu. i realize it's faulty but we dont have intel partners or authorized dealers in my country (online customer support verified its still under warranty) and since its booting into windows, i just need to be able to re-enable on-board VGA and disregard the option for PCIe completely. Any ideas??

Comment: Did you remove the pci-e vqa card?

Comment: yes i did after trying other cards

Comment: Strange, most bios's will default to onboard video when no other card is present in the system.

Comment: so ive been told by intel customer support

Comment: remove all non essential hardware from the motherboard, only leave psu, cpu+fan, memory, disconnect-remove everything else, then see if it will output video.

Comment: i managed to gain access via remote desktop. is there anything i can do? the display adapter is missing from the device manager but shows under hidden devices as not connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to finally solve this. Once i realized and made sure it's actually booting normally into windows without a display, i plugged the hard drive on another system, booted and enabled remote desktop and disabled firewall. I then plugged it back to the original system and fired it up, logged in remotely. After realizing there isnt much to be done remotely (intel AMT wouldve been nice!), i downloaded and installed a newer bios. It was still without display and beeping, but for some reason the power-button menu worked and i managed to get display.